# Expecting SOAP12HeaderImpl as parent, got class org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl Java Client

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, wsdl2java, wso2-esb

I've generated a Stub using Axis2 for given WSDL using WSO2-ESB. So I've to add following parameters to header when i call the WS

1. Simple Authentication (Username , Password)
2. WS-Addressing (true) - WS-A
3. WS-Reliable Messaging (true) - WS-RM

To add WS-RM to Header I've used [ApacheSandesha2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/sandesha/userGuide.html)

My Code Snippet is,

```
 HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator  basicAuthentication = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();

basicAuthentication.setUsername("xxxxxxxx");
basicAuthentication.setPassword("xxxxxxxx");

System.out.println("Basic Authentication have generated");

BankingSaviPaySoapStub bankingSaviPaySoapStub = new BankingSaviPaySoapStub();

/**Setting Web Service Authentication Properties to the Stub*/
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, Boolean.FALSE);
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, basicAuthentication);

/**Setting WSA Properties to the Stub*/
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(AddressingConstants.WS_ADDRESSING_VERSION,
  AddressingConstants.Submission.WSA_NAMESPACE);
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(AddressingConstants.INCLUDE_OPTIONAL_HEADERS,
  Boolean.TRUE); 


/**Setting WS-RM Properties to the Stub*/
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().engageModule("addressing");

System.out.println("engaged addressing module.");
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().engageModule("sandesha2");

System.out.println("engaged sandesha2 module.");
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(SandeshaClientConstants.OFFERED_SEQUENCE_ID, SandeshaUtil.getUUID());
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(SandeshaClientConstants.RM_SPEC_VERSION, Sandesha2Constants.SPEC_VERSIONS.v1_1);
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(SandeshaClientConstants.SEQUENCE_KEY, SandeshaUtil.getUUID());
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setTransportInProtocol(Constants.TRANSPORT_HTTP);
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(SandeshaClientConstants.AcksTo, AddressingConstants.Final.WSA_ANONYMOUS_URL);

/*Set SOAP Version.*/
bankingSaviPaySoapStub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setSoapVersionURI(org.apache.axis2.namespace.Constants.URI_SOAP12_ENV);
```

When I call the web service method using the above code. I get following Error.

```
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Sandesha2 got an exception when processing an out message: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: Expecting SOAP12HeaderImpl as parent, got class org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl at org.apache.sandesha2.handlers.SandeshaOutHandler.invoke(SandeshaOutHandler.java:166)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:427)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.sendAsync(OutInAxisOperation.java:312)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at com.fg.ws.BankingSaviPaySoapStub.startpayAnyone(BankingSaviPayanyone1_0SoapStub.java:413)
        at com.fg.ws.app.App.<init>(App.java:148)
        at com.fg.ws.app.App.main(App.java:156)
Caused by: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: Expecting SOAP12HeaderImpl as parent, got class org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl
```

I've Printed the ServiceClient Options. All the options are binded like below.

```
{Sandesha2AcksTo=http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAddressingVersion=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing, includeOptionalHeaders=true, _NTLM_DIGEST_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION_=org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HttpTransportProperties$Authenticator@f539f96, __CHUNKED__=false, Sandesha2OfferedSequenceId=urn:uuid:286E463BCCB1EC15301446014283931, Sandesha2RMSpecVersion=Spec_2007_02, Sandesha2SequenceKey=urn:uuid:286E463BCCB1EC15301446014283932}
```